# how to use call on multiple tables in a php for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, content-management-system

I'd like to display results from two tables in my MYSQL database using the for each loop. Currently I have split both tables into two separate loops like this:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
     foreach (array_reverse ($articles) as $article){?>
            <div class="greyvertical midtopmargin item leftpadding rightpadding">
                <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><img src="../lifestyle/photos/articles/<?php echo $article['photo_folder']; ?>/<?php echo $article['photo_1']; ?>" alt="item">
                <h5 class="whitetext text2 extrabold smalltoppadding leftpadding"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></h5></a>
                <p class="meta whitetext leftpadding smalltoppadding">
                    <?php echo $article['article_summary']; ?></p>
                <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>" class="whitetext text2 mediumfont leftpadding midbottommargin">READ ME</a>
            </div>
        <?php if (++$i == 5) break;
} ?>

    <?php
    $i = 0;
     foreach (array_reverse ($posts) as $post){?>
            <div class="greyvertical midtopmargin item leftpadding rightpadding">
                <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>"><img src="../lifestyle/photos/blog/<?php echo $post['photo_folder']; ?>/<?php echo $post['photo_bg']; ?>" alt="item">
                <h5 class="whitetext extrabold text2 leftpadding smalltoppadding"><?php echo $post['post_title']; ?></h5></a>
                <p class="meta leftpadding whitetext smalltoppadding">
                    <?php echo $post['post_summary']; ?></p>
                <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>" class="whitetext text2 mediumfont leftpadding midbottommargin">READ ME</a>
            </div>
            <?php if (++$i == 5) break;
            } ?>
```

As you can see they are almost identical with slight differences but I am completely stuck on how to combine the two without them being separate as it is now. Could anyone let me know in layman's terms how to combine the two loops into one? I.e I want to combine the articles and posts tables so they will be displayed as one rather than separately. thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What's in `$article` and `$posts`?

Comment: It seems like somewhere along your development you deviated from the pattern IMHO. To address your issue -- you should simply make a conditional to check for the existence of a value that only occurs in either $article or $posts, then react accordingly within the foreach.

Comment: $article = new Article;
$post = new Postl; $articles = $article->fetch_all();
$posts = $post->fetch_all();

Comment: It would seem that you have control over each variable from the ground up, why not simply push the two arrays together and check the array key value, then use ternary variable assignment for the small nuances you need to switch?

Comment: so for example something like $article= new Article; new Postl; ?

Answer (score 0):

The comments made on your question make sense and you should take them into account, but there is a way of iterating over two arrays at once by using PHP's [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php). Here is a much simplified example of how this could work for you:-

```
$articles = array('article 1','article 2','article 3');
$posts = array('post 1', 'post 2', 'post 3');

$iterator1 = new ArrayIterator($articles);
$iterator2 = new ArrayIterator($posts);

$multiIterator = new MultipleIterator();
$multiIterator->attachIterator($iterator1);
$multiIterator->attachIterator($iterator2);

foreach($multiIterator as $combinedArray){
    echo $combinedArray[0] . "<br/>\n";
    echo $combinedArray[1] . "<br/>\n";
}
```

Output:-

```
article 1
post 1
article 2
post 2
article 3
post 3
```